# Getting nil value from entity in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am following raywenderlich's tutorial for Core Data : [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173972/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial-2)

the issue I am facing is that in this snippet of code :

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: managedContext)!
let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,insertInto: managedContext)
```

The entity value is returned `nil` and app gets crashed . Is there something that I missed because I have tried 3-4 times but still the same issue

Comment: Not related to problem, but never do force unwrap, at least your app will not crash.

Comment: Also check for data fault while using core data..

Answer (score -1):

If you say what you say is correct (crashing on the mentioned line) then the Person entity does not exist in the data model.

Please verify that the person exists in the model:

[image]

Also following the linked tutorial I suspect you're calling the save method, like so:

```
func save(name: String) {

  guard let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
    return
  }

  // 1
  let managedContext =
    appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

  // 2
  let entity =
    NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person",
                               in: managedContext)!

  let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                               insertInto: managedContext)

  // 3
  person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

  // 4
  do {
    try managedContext.save()
    people.append(person)
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
}
```

Which suggests that you'll also have to check for the `name` attribute on the `Person` entity:

[image]

I hope this helps you.